# Transforming a Locale[] to a CharSequence[] to place inside a ListPreference in Android App

Tags: java, android, locale, listpreference

In my Android app, I want to place a list of all the available Locales on the phone into a `ListPreference` in my `PreferenceActivity` so that the user can select which one he wants to change the output of the currency symbol.

So far I've tried this:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) root.findPreference("list");
Locale[] availableLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();

CharSequence[] entries = new CharSequence[Locale.getAvailableLocales().length];
CharSequence[] entriesVal = new CharSequence[Locale.getAvailableLocales().length];

for (int i = 0; i < entriesVal.length; i++) {
        entries[i] = availableLocales[i].getDisplayCountry();
        entriesVal[i] = Integer.toString(i);
}

listPref.setEntries(entries);
listPref.setEntryValues(entriesVal);
```

I get a JavaNullPointer Exception on this line `listPref.setEntries(entries);`, so I believe that I haven't formed my `CharSequence` properly, so the `ListPReference` cannot read it.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems more likely that `listPref` is actually null - i.e. `root.findPreference("list")` is returning `null`. That's what you should look into (and at least check) first.

Comment: YOu are correct, what the value of the ListPreference I should be looking for then? not this one: android:key="list"

Comment: @zeroFiG: I can't say I've ever done any Android development myself, so I'm guessing really... but have you called `addPreferencesFromResource`?

Comment: @zeroFiG: Are you sure it shouldn't be `root.addPreferencesFromResource`? Or call `findPreference` on `this` instead of `root`?

Comment: Ahh there you go! ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) this.findPreference("list"); Thanks!